# what is the easiest way to convert / map a JSON string to a javabean?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string that I read in and would like to parse / map it to a JavaBean so I can use it in my Java code. What is the easiest way / library to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

XStream is renowned for its ease of use and supports JSON:

http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a JSON library to do just that..

http://code.google.com/p/svenson/

With svenson you would do something like:

```
// assume json to be a JSON dataset as String
MyBean bean = JSONParser.defaultJSONParser().parse(MyBean.class, json);
```

Svenson gives you free choice of either using maps/lists or your own POJOs to convert data to and from JSON.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial)? Like one of the other ones mentioned, mapping is quite simple:

MyBean bean = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyBean.class);

handles Maps, Lists, primitives, beans; with proper generics support and full configurability of mapping process.